# Finding the measure of $\angle AEB$ given a figure

Tags: geometry, circles

In the given figure, $O$ is the center of the circle and  $$ \angle AOB =120$$

[image]

How could I find the measure of $\angle AEB$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With $A,B,O$ fixed, $C$ and $D$ determine $E$, so $\angle AEB$ depends on $C$ and $D$, no? Then what are those?

Comment: You cannot find <AEB. The most we can know is that <ADB = <ACB = <AOB/2. Imagine holding point C still while varying point D. The angle <AEB changes.

Comment: Agree with anon, more info needed. Angle ABD is 60 degrees, so angle AEB is 60 plus angle EAD, which angle depends on where C and D are.

Comment: It seems we are missing a piece of information, such as the $\angle$ for $C$ or $D.$  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: To be more specific about the ambiguity: if $AC$ and $BD$ were diameters (containing $O$), then $\angle AEB = \angle AOB = 120^{\circ}$. On the other hand, if $C$ and $D$ were to coincide (along the longer arc $AB$), then $E$ would coincide with them, so that $\angle AEB = \angle ACB = \angle ADB = 60^{\circ}$ (by the Inscribed Angle Theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle ). With $C$ and $D$ elsewhere, $\angle AEB$ is something else. This, even though the $\angle C$ and $\angle D$ --with $C$ and $D$ along the longer arc $AB$-- are *always* $60^{\circ}$ (by the IAT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the measure of the angle depends on the positions of $C$ and $D$:

[image: animation]